# Mongoose call a function for a field when inserting a document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Below code snippet is working fine.

```
function simple() {
  return 10000;
}

db.Invoice.create({
  items: selectedItems,
  _id: simple("userid")
});
```

But if I change `simple function` to this

```
async function getNextSequence(sequenceName) {
  const sequenceDocument = await db.Counter.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: sequenceName },
    { $inc: { seq: 1 } },
    { new: true }
  );

  console.log("seq", sequenceDocument);

  return sequenceDocument.seq;
}

db.Invoice.create({
  items: selectedItems,
  _id: getNextSequence("userid")
});
```

This gives me an error.

> ValidationError: Invoice validation failed: _id: Cast to Number failed
>   for value "Promise {  }" at path "_id"

Why could this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getNextSequence` is an asynchronous function which needs to be awaited - otherwise you're trying to save `Promise` to your MongoDB which is not supported. Try:

```
db.Invoice.create({
    items: selectedItems, 
    _id: await getNextSequence('userid'),
})
```